# Python: Replace character in a string based on input

Tags: python, string

I have a program that takes a string input, and an integer input.
The integer determines 2 things, how many times the string is printed, and which character in the string is visible, otherwise replaced by "."

For example - 
String: Hello World
Integer: 3

Should show as:

```
H..l..W..l.
.e..o..o..d
..l.. ..r..
```

Basically printing diagonal text.

How would I go about having every 3rd character in the string shown, otherwise replaced by "."? Regardless of the inputted string and beginning with the first.

I only need the function, I got the rest of the code.

The code so far to is this (not compact):

```
stringVar = input("String: ")
countVar = input("Count: ")

countInt = int(countVar)
stringInt = len(stringVar)

if countInt > stringInt:
    print("Number should be between 1 and the lenght of the string!")
    exit()

if countInt < 1:
    print("Number should be between 1 and the lenght of the string!")
    exit()

count = 1        

while count <= countInt:
    print(stringVar)
    count = count + 1
```

I just need a way to also replace the characters in StringVar.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write this yourself? If so, can you provide the code?

Comment: Just added the code so far.

Comment: This reads like homework. Beware, if you take the one line answers below, your teacher will immediately know you didn't do this yourself.

Comment: That is **precisely** why I made my answer one line.

Comment: Thanks! It's an old exercise problem I'm using to practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> message = 'Hello World'
>>> print ('\n'.join([''.join(['.' if (j-i) % n else c for j, c in enumerate('hello world')]) for i in range(n)]))
h..l..w..l.
.e..o..o..d
..l.. ..r..
```

The magic happens in `(j-i) % n`. Modulus is positive if not divisible by `n`. Beyond that there are two list comprehensions, outer for each line, inner for each character

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'Hello World!!!'
n = 3
rep = '.'

for j in range(n):
    print(''.join([v if (i - j)%n == 0 else rep for i, v in enumerate(s)]))

# H..l..W..l..!.
# .e..o..o..d..!
# ..l.. ..r..!..
```

The code iterates over the required number of lines (`0,1,2` for `n=3`). The `''.join(...)` method checks if `(i - j)%n == 0` to decide when to print the letter, otherwise prints the `rep` string.